# Cancel Notification on App Uninstall

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-notifications, android-applicationinfo

In my code, I create a notification that once clicked tries to uninstall an app identified by its package name. I want the notification to be disappear only if the app is successfully uninstalled. If the user clicks "cancel" for app uninstall pop-up, I would like the notification to persist.

Any ideas how I can do that?

```
    Uri packageURI = Uri.parse("package:" + package_name);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, packageURI);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    PendingIntent pintent=PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,intent,0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    builder.setContentIntent(pintent);
    builder.setContentTitle(uninstallAppNotificationTitle);
    builder.setTicker(uninstallAppNotificationTicker);
    builder.setContentText(uninstallAppNotificationContent);
    builder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);
    builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
    builder.setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
    builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(uninstallAppNotificationContent)) ;
    builder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);
    builder.setOngoing(true);

    Notification notification = builder.build();
    notification.contentIntent = pintent;
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(TAG, uninstallNotificationId, notification);
```

Comment: Show the code for "app uninstall pop-up" which I hope you mean some kind of AlertDialog.

Comment: I have posted the code. @Marcus

Answer (score 1):

There is a way. you can create a broadcast receiver for it

[Package removed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED)

I am sure you are persisting the notification id somewhere. just use that id to cancel the notification. have one uninstall id or package id fixed for each app, receive the intent in broadcast receiver and cancel the notification using Notification Manager.